# Setting Button background Image wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml

I want to design a button with 2 background images(first one when enabled , second when disabled). As shown below.
How do i do it in button style ?

tried something like this . But Content is not a property here.

```
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}"  x:Key="LinkButton">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border x:Name="Overlay" CornerRadius="2">
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
                           <!--<Setter TargetName="Overlay" Property="Content" Value="Red"/>-->
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15892290/how-to-change-set-button-background-image-in-c-sharp-wpf-code

Comment: I want this to be done in XAML.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do it in xaml then have two images inside the button using a canvas. 
Using edit style for trigger change the visibility of the images you need inside the button.

i think you can get the point. Mark useful if it is really useful
thank you

Answer (score 0):

You may do it with help of Style and Converter like this:

**Opacity converter:**

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace EnableButton
{
    public class OpacityConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return (bool) value ? 1 : 0.5;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

**Your Xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="EnableButton.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EnableButton"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:OpacityConverter x:Key="OpacityConverter"/>
        <Style x:Key="DisableIcon" TargetType="Image">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}, Path=IsEnabled, Converter={StaticResource OpacityConverter}}"/>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Height="24" IsEnabled="False">
            <Image Style="{StaticResource DisableIcon}" Source="Open_22.png"/>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Now if you change **IsEnable** property of the button you will see the result. I change **Opacity** property of the **Image** from 100% to 50% when the parent button becomes disabled in **OpacityConverter** so you may fix this if you want another digits.

**Update**

I thought a little about your question. I think if the button becomes disabled it would be nice not only to change the **Opacity** of the image but also to convert an images picture into monochromic. So I found this solution (add reference to **Microsoft.Expression.Effects.dll** and add xmlns:ee="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/effects" into the form before trying):

```
<Window x:Class="EnableButton.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EnableButton"

        xmlns:ee="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/effects"

        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>

        <Style x:Key="DisableImageStyle" TargetType="Image">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}, Path=IsEnabled}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.4"/>
                    <Setter Property="Effect">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ee:EmbossedEffect/>
                            <!--This effect is also looks nice-->
                            <!--<ee:MonochromeEffect/>-->
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>

        <Button Height="40" IsEnabled="False">
            <Image Style="{StaticResource DisableImageStyle}" Source="Open_22.png"/>
        </Button>

    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Notice that I don't use any converters now!

Comment: Can i store this style as resource dictionary so thati can use it across buttons.

Comment: If you mean creating a resource dictionary file and merging it in App.xaml than yes sure :)

Comment: @user1687824 I updated my answer a little. See **Update** section

Comment: IS Microsoft.Expression.Effects.dll available in 4.0 ?

Comment: @user1687824 This library ships with Blend and have both 4.0 and 4.5 versions. Make sure that you have Microsoft Blend installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataTrigger for change background image of button. below is the link may help.

[WPF Change button background image when clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16319063/change-button-background-image-when-clicked)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you are setting the style of your button but if you are able to put both images into the style then you can change the visibility when `IsEnabled` is changed.

```
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}"  x:Key="LinkButton">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border x:Name="Overlay" CornerRadius="2">
                    <Image x:Name="Enabled" Source="{StaticResource EnabledImg}"/>
                    <Image x:Name="Disabled" Source="{StaticResource DisabledImg}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                       <Setter TargetName="Disabled" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                       <Setter TargetName="Enabled" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```