# Changing WPF Button Background Image

Tags: c#, wpf, image, button, wpf-controls

I read the excellent advise regarding how to change an button's background image file from here:

[How to change\set button background image in C# WPF code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15892290/how-to-change-set-button-background-image-in-c-sharp-wpf-code)

Notably the following code:

```
var brush = new ImageBrush();
brush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/ContentImage.png",UriKind.Relative));
button1.Background = brush;
```

Along with telling visual studios it is a "content" file and "Copy Always".

It seems to work, but whenever my cursor hovers over the image, then the image will disappear.

This cursor hovering problem does not occur if instead I specify the image file in the xaml.  But, I want to be changing the image file from the C# code.

Any advise?

Thanks,
Howard

Comment: Most likely your xaml hover template style inherits from the non-hover template whereas assigning it from code only changes the non-hover button style.

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2902861/479512) see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found a working solution - based on the webpage http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/634111/How-to-remove-Glow-of-Button-on-Mouse-hover-in-WPF

A little background: This is an application I wrote about ten years ago with Java/Netbeans which grew quite large over the years.  Because Java/Netbeans no longer supports s/w development of desktop applications, I am porting it to Visual Studio WPF C#.

The xaml:

```
<Button x:Name="buttonDigit1"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="30" Height="50"
                        Click="buttonDigit1_Click" MouseRightButtonDown="buttonDigit1_RightClick" MouseWheel="buttonDigit1_MouseWheelMoved">
                    <Image Width="30" Height="50"></Image>
                    <Button.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                            <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Button.Template>
                </Button>
```

This is repeated for a total of nine buttons.
A serial i/o thread in a different class reads data from a radio over a serial port.  If the radio's frequency changes it calls a method in this window class to change the displayed frequency.

The C# code in the window class:

```
// class global variables
    static ImageBrush[] digitBrush = new ImageBrush[10];
    static BitmapImage[] digitImage = new BitmapImage[10];
    static String radioDigitStyle = " ";

    public void displayFrequency(String frequency0)
    {
        int frequency_int = HowardUtils.frequency_int(frequency0);
        String frequency_str = HowardUtils.frequency_str(frequency_int);
        textBoxFreqVFOA.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => {
            textBoxFreqVFOA.Text = frequency_str;
        }));

        // Display the frequency in the digits display on RADIO Control Dialog
        String frequency = frequency0.Replace(".", "");  // Eliminate "."s
        frequency = HowardUtils.removeLeadingZeros(frequency);// Elmiinate leading 0s
        while (frequency.Length < 10) {
            // Add leading zeros for 10 digits
            frequency = "0" + frequency;
        }
        if (Global.DEBUG_RADIO) Console.WriteLine("displayFrequency frequency='" + frequency + "'");

        String[] digit_str = new String[9];
        digit_str[0] = frequency.Substring(1, 1);
        digit_str[1] = frequency.Substring(2, 1);
        digit_str[2] = frequency.Substring(3, 1);
        digit_str[3] = frequency.Substring(4, 1);
        digit_str[4] = frequency.Substring(5, 1);
        digit_str[5] = frequency.Substring(6, 1);
        digit_str[6] = frequency.Substring(7, 1);
        digit_str[7] = frequency.Substring(8, 1);
        digit_str[8] = frequency.Substring(9, 1);
        if (Global.DEBUG_RADIO) {
            Console.WriteLine("displayFrequency digit_str=" +
                digit_str[0] + digit_str[1] + digit_str[2] +
                digit_str[3] + digit_str[4] + digit_str[5] +
                digit_str[6] + digit_str[7] + digit_str[8]);
        }
        int[] digit = new int[9];
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            if (digit_str[i] == " ") { digit_str[i] = "0"; }    // Convert blank to zero.
            digit[i] = Convert.ToInt32(digit_str[i]);
        }
        if (Global.DEBUG_RADIO) Console.WriteLine("debug - digit_str[i]='" + 
            digit_str[0] + digit_str[1] + digit_str[2] + " " +
            digit_str[3] + digit_str[4] + digit_str[5] + " " +
            digit_str[6] + digit_str[7] + digit_str[8] + "'"); //xxxxx

        if (radioDigitStyle != Global.Settings.GetRadioDigits()) {
            // radio digits style has changed.
            //ImageBrush[] digitBrush = new ImageBrush[10];
            for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                digitBrush[i] = new ImageBrush();
            }

            switch (Global.Settings.GetRadioDigits())
            {
                case "Blue Black Digits":
                    digitImage[0] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/0BCKBLUE.GIF", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[1] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/1BCKBLUE.GIF", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[2] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/2BCKBLUE.GIF", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[3] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/3BCKBLUE.GIF", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[4] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/4BCKBLUE.GIF", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[5] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/5BCKBLUE.GIF", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[6] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/6BCKBLUE.GIF", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[7] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/7BCKBLUE.GIF", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[8] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/8BCKBLUE.GIF", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[9] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/9BCKBLUE.GIF", UriKind.Relative));
                    break;
                case "Computer Digits":
                    digitImage[0] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/0COMPUTE.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[1] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/1COMPUTE.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[2] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/2COMPUTE.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[3] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/3COMPUTE.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[4] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/4COMPUTE.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[5] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/5COMPUTE.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[6] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/6COMPUTE.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[7] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/7COMPUTE.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[8] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/8COMPUTE.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[9] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/9COMPUTE.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    break;
                case "Black Yellow Digits":
                    digitImage[0] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/0BCK-YLW.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[1] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/1BCK-YLW.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[2] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/2BCK-YLW.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[3] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/3BCK-YLW.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[4] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/4BCK-YLW.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[5] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/5BCK-YLW.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[6] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/6BCK-YLW.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[7] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/7BCK-YLW.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[8] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/8BCK-YLW.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[9] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/9BCK-YLW.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    break;
                case "Black Turq Digits":
                    digitImage[0] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/0BCKTURQ.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[1] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/1BCKTURQ.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[2] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/2BCKTURQ.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[3] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/3BCKTURQ.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[4] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/4BCKTURQ.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[5] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/5BCKTURQ.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[6] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/6BCKTURQ.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[7] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/7BCKTURQ.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[8] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/8BCKTURQ.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[9] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/9BCKTURQ.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    break;
                case "Black Red Digits":
                    digitImage[0] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/0BCK-RED.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[1] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/1BCK-RED.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[2] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/2BCK-RED.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[3] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/3BCK-RED.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[4] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/4BCK-RED.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[5] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/5BCK-RED.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[6] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/6BCK-RED.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[7] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/7BCK-RED.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[8] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/8BCK-RED.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[9] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/9BCK-RED.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    break;
                case "Black Pink Digits":
                    digitImage[0] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/0BCKPINK.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[1] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/1BCKPINK.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[2] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/2BCKPINK.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[3] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/3BCKPINK.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[4] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/4BCKPINK.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[5] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/5BCKPINK.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[6] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/6BCKPINK.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[7] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/7BCKPINK.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[8] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/8BCKPINK.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[9] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/9BCKPINK.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    break;
                case "Black Orange Digits":
                    digitImage[0] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/0BCKORNG.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[1] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/1BCKORNG.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[2] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/2BCKORNG.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[3] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/3BCKORNG.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[4] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/4BCKORNG.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[5] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/5BCKORNG.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[6] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/6BCKORNG.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[7] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/7BCKORNG.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[8] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/8BCKORNG.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[9] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/9BCKORNG.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    break;
                case "Black Old Digits":
                    digitImage[0] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/0BCK-OLD.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[1] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/1BCK-OLD.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[2] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/2BCK-OLD.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[3] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/3BCK-OLD.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[4] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/4BCK-OLD.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[5] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/5BCK-OLD.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[6] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/6BCK-OLD.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[7] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/7BCK-OLD.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[8] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/8BCK-OLD.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[9] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/9BCK-OLD.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    break;
                case "EVA01 Digits":
                    digitImage[0] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/0EVA00.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[1] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/1EVA00.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[2] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/2EVA00.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[3] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/3EVA00.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[4] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/4EVA00.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[5] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/5EVA00.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[6] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/6EVA00.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[7] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/7EVA00.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[8] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/8EVA00.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[9] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/9EVA00.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    break;
                case "DigitF Digits":
                    digitImage[0] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/0DIGIF.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[1] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/1DIGIF.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[2] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/2DIGIF.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[3] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/3DIGIF.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[4] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/4DIGIF.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[5] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/5DIGIF.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[6] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/6DIGIF.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[7] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/7DIGIF.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[8] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/8DIGIF.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    digitImage[9] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/9DIGIF.gif", UriKind.Relative));
                    break;
            } //end switch 
            for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
                digitBrush[i] = new ImageBrush( digitImage[i] );
            }
            //
            radioDigitStyle = Global.Settings.GetRadioDigits();
        } // end of radio digits style has changed.

        System.Windows.Controls.Button[] radioDigitButtons = {
            buttonDigit1,
            buttonDigit2,
            buttonDigit3,
            buttonDigit4,
            buttonDigit5,
            buttonDigit6,
            buttonDigit7,
            buttonDigit8,
            buttonDigit9 };

        for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            buttonDigit1.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                radioDigitButtons[i].Background = digitBrush[digit[i]];
            }));
        }
        RadioUtils.DisplayVFOFrequency();
    } // end displayFrequency(String frequency0)
```

The user can left click on a digit to increase the frequency value, and right click on a digit to decrease the value.  Also the mouse wheel can do the same. But, I did not show the code for it.

The first answer solved the problem, but just would not work when inside a public method to be called from a different class.  However, the information was useful and changed my internet searches for a solution.

I've been hammering on this code for days to find a solution, and yes it can be improved upon.

Answer (score 2):

In order to change WPF Button background image, for example, from `Images/ContentImage.png` to `Images/ContentImage1.png` on MouseOver event you can add `ControlTemplate` containing `Image` control and use the `Trigger` like shown in the following XAML snippet:

*Listing 1. Change Button Image on MouseOver using XAML Triggers*

```
<Button Name="button1">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Image Name="img1" Source="Images/ContentImage.png" />
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                    <Setter TargetName="img1"  
                            Property="Source"  
                            Value="Images/ContentImage1.png" />
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Another solution will allow to change the

*Listing 2. Changing Button Image on click (XAML)*

```
    <Button Name ="button1" Click="button1_Click">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Image x:Name="image1">
                    <Image.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                            <Setter Property="Source"  Value="Images/ContentImage.png" />
                        </Style>
                    </Image.Style>
                </Image>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
```

*Listing 3. C# code behind (button1.click event handler)*

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs a)
{
    Image _img= button1.Template.FindName("image1", button1) as Image;
    Style _imgStyle = new Style { TargetType = typeof(Image) };
     _imgStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Image.SourceProperty, new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/YourAssemblyName;component//Images/ContentImage1.png"))));
    _img.Style = _imgStyle;
}
```

Hope this may help.

Comment: Thanks.  I will be changing the button's image many times inside the C# code.  So, I do not want to place the image file's name into the XAML file.  Do you know how to do that within the C# WPF code?

Comment: Please refer to the extended answer. Best regards,

Comment: I found in general that if the xaml contains a source image file, then the program C# code can not change the image.  Same thing with your example.  With or without the image files specified in xaml code, it just does not stop the problem.  I have read that it has to do with Chrome.  This page sounds like it has the solution:      https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Changing-a-WPF-Button-212386c6  However, I can not get it working - problem with the sample code's app.xaml file.  copying the author's xaml file does not work.  Without it the simple style.axml file will not work.

Comment: This code snippet has been tested and works just fine. Should it be an Image control, then it's gonna be a different story (re; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36203201/how-to-make-the-image-pop-up-on-mouse-hovering-in-c-sharp-wpf/36203345#36203345). Not sure what do you mean by "it has to do with Chrome" (this is a WPF app). Just follow this solution and it should work. Best regards,

Comment: If you clicked on the code.msdn.microsoft.com link, you will see the author dealing with exactly the problem I am having.  His solution looks like a thousand lines of code.  As I have stated, if I place an image file source into the xaml file, then it is impossible for my C# code to change the image to a different image.  There is no compile time, nor run time error - it just will not occur.  But, I appreciate you trying to help.  I may just make hundreds of users live with this little problem - just too advanced a thing to force WPF to not do its default behavior.

Comment: Instead of adding your xml to my existing button, I created a new button cut and pasting your xaml code - only changing the image file location and adding width and height to the button size.  At runtime there is a null error - apparently the FindName is not working right.

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification. Please refer to my extended answer pertinent to your case. Best regards,

Comment: Ok, that works well.  However, if I move the code out of the click method into a public method which uses button1.Dispatcher.Invoke, then the same lines will not work.  I do not know why.   button1.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => {
                  Image _img = button1.Template.FindName("image1", button1) as Image;
                  Style _imgStyle = new Style { TargetType = typeof(Image) };
                  _imgStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Image.SourceProperty, new BitmapImage(new Uri("digits/1BCKBLUE.GIF", UriKind.Relative))));
                  _img.Style = _imgStyle;
            }));

Comment: I've provided detailed answer to your question. As per your comments, the solution works well, so I suggest to mark the answer as accepted and to close this comments thread. Should you have more questions, please post them separately. Best regards,